# Scaling issue with a view in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue with scaling when using a view in MS SQL Server 2005. My defined view returns the data of interest on a small test dataset; however, when I try to return the view on a large dataset (>10000 rows), my query just runs and runs without returning.  Is this an error in the efficiency of the view definition, or maybe do I need to include indexing? Are there other ways that I could make the view return data more quickly/efficiently so that it can be practically used?

My current view definition is as follows: -

```
CREATE VIEW reportedProjects AS
  SELECT vc.projectID, vc.sampleID, vc.runID, vc.ngsSubpanel,
  va.[HGVS_c], va.[HGVS_p], va.geneID, va.transcriptID,
  sc.score, sc.scorer, sc.checker

  FROM dbo.varCall vc, dbo.varAnnotation va, dbo.varScore sc


  WHERE vc.varCallID = va.varCallID
  AND vc.variantID = va.variantID
  AND va.variantID = sc.variantID
  AND va.transcriptID = sc.transcriptID;

GO
```

-- **Update** --

Apologies for any red herrings this may have thrown up for readers. A change of base table columns (not listed in the above problem description) to join on within the view has solved my issue. All suggestions offered were much appreciated though.

Comment: What indexes do you currently have?  That would be the first place to look.

Comment: Have you tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE` clause with an `AND`?

Comment: @MarkWagoner I haven't created any indexes yet, wasn't sure of the best way to approach this. Would I be better creating indexes on the view itself or on the tables that the view draw data from?

Comment: For 10000 rows even without index it should work pretty fast.

Comment: Your question amounts to, "I haven't done any performance optimization, and when I use a large number of rows, it performs poorly".

Comment: Why not offer some constructive advice instead instead of unhelpful criticisms?

Comment: @ChrisWall, yes, you should start by adding indexes to the tables accessed via the view.  A view just encapsulates the query.  The query plan is driven from available indexes on the underlying tables.

Comment: Start by indexing the tables.   Indexing the view itself should be a last resort.

Comment: @δοῦλοςἸησοῦςΧριστός @Mark @Dan @Tab Thanks for the advice guys.  I have changed the view definition to use  `INNER JOIN` rather than `WHERE` clause.  The underlying tables do have indexes due to the primary keys that I created on them (varCallID is the PK in dbo.varCall; variantID and transcriptID are composite PK in dbo.varScore) and I have added an index to the varAnnotation on the transcriptID. Despite this the query still does not return.  Does anyone have any further advice? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes for varCallID, variantID, and transcriptID; then use joins and see how it performs